# utf8 and ISO 8859-1 encoding references trouble

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies

I have to use one particular template ( am obliged to use it for my thesis) it uses `\bibliographystyle{plain}` Ihave both english and frensh text on it (for abstract and résumé) there is no problem for characters like ( é, ç...) but some of references does not appear they are replaced by [?] knowing that foe encoding `\RequirePackage[latin1]{inputenc}` how to fix this problem please!

```
 \documentclass{article}
  \RequirePackage[latin1]{inputenc}
  \RequirePackage{fancyhdr}

   blabla \cite{nayak2015comprehensive, byun2002applications, shah2004sequential, fletcher2009support, cornuejols2011apprentissage, byun2002applications}
  @article{nayak2015comprehensive,
   title={A comprehensive survey on support vector machine in data mining 
   tasks: applications \& challenges},
   author={Nayak, Janmenjoy and Naik, Bighnaraj and Behera, HS},
   journal={International Journal of Database Theory and Application},
   volume={8},
   number={1},
   pages={169--186},
   year={2015}
   }

    @inproceedings{shah2004sequential,
    title={Sequential k-nearest neighbor pattern recognition for usable 
    speech classification},
    author={Shah, Jashmin K and Smolenski, Brett Y and Yantorno, Robert E 
    and Iyer, Ananth N},
    booktitle={Signal Processing Conference, 2004 12th European},
    pages={741--744},
    year={2004},
    organization={IEEE}
    }
     @misc{fletcher2009support,
     title  = {Support vector machines explained},
    author = {Fletcher, Tristan},
    journal= {University College London, London},
    year   = {2009},
    howpublished = "\url{http://sutikno.blog.undip.ac.id/files/2011/11/SVM-
    Explained.pdf}",
    note   = {Accessed: 2017-04-30}
    }
     @inbook{cornuejols2011apprentissage,
     title={Apprentissage artificiel: concepts et algorithmes},
     author={Cornu{\'e}jols, Antoine and Miclet, Laurent},
     year={2011},
     pages={279--309},
     publisher={Editions Eyrolles}
      }
     @incollection{byun2002applications,
     title={Applications of support vector machines for pattern recognition: 
     A survey},
     author={Byun, Hyeran and Lee, Seong-Whan},
     booktitle={Pattern recognition with support vector machines},
      pages={213--236},
     year={2002},
     publisher={Springer}
     }
```

\end{document}

knowing that my references work well on other template but this one no how to fix this problm please! here is the error I got [image: error]

**Edited**
here is the link to the template [my template](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_6RXQUqktUOUG9peTZyOVBXZjg/view?usp=sharing) in fact I have created a littele example ( since I could not publish my thesis ...) the error has disappeared but my references still [?]

Comment: Can't you really use `biblatex+biber`? It would solve the problem. The default style for `biblatex` is `numeric`, which is more or less plain, and it's easy to customise.

Comment: Try ansinew instead of latin1.

Comment: Working with the code fragments you've posted so far, I am utterly unable to reproduce any of the problems you say are occurring. In particular, the five bib entries you've posted generate no problems at all. Please post code that actually generates problems and/or error messages.

Comment: I tend to avoid non-utf8 encodings for TeX input like the plague, especially for French stuff (damn, `latin1` does not even have “œ”, if I'm not mistaken). And yeah, as others stated, `biber` should be used to avoid trouble. And be careful to have an input file actually matching the encoding declared to `inputenc`. Sometimes the issues simply come from the fact that the user types stuff in one encoding and tells `inputenc` that something else is used.

Comment: @Mico as I have posted I got the error as you can see on the figure honestly ( an regarding what you said ) I wonder what is the origin of this error ! :( and why some of my references did not appear

Comment: @UlrikeFischer did this change anything it is a template given by the university am supposed not to change it to have same style as it is described for all students

Comment: @mirette - The screenshot you posted only refers to line 13 of some file. However, the screenshot gives no indication that the errors are connected to any bibliographic entries. Incidentally, virtually all editors nowadays save their contents utf8-encoded. I would like to suggest that you change from `\RequirePackage[latin1]{inputenc}` to `\RequirePackage[utf8]{inputenc}` and see what happens.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Same thing with  ansinewA  a lot of my references are [?]

Comment: @Bernard  soory how to do this (excuse me am not very familiar with latex but as described in rules we have not to change we have to use bibtex does biblatex very different !!

Comment: @Mico okey I will try what you said , yeah but line 13 when I refer to it it does not contain any thing since as you can see it does not refer to any file but I said that problm is due to bibliographies because there is [?] where it has to be for example [2] or ... whatever ! but am going to try  `\RequirePackage[utf8]{inputenc}` am I supposed to change anything else !!

Comment: unfortunately @Mico it gives me a lot of error ( since I have é ç.. paragraph and my references still [?]

Comment: @mirette - Please, please stop your shouting: There is absolutely no need for single and double exclamation marks in any of your comments. I, for one, certainly do not appreciate being shouted at. A basic suggestion: Instead of shouting more and more loudly, please turn to providing some real, tangible information about how your files are actually encoded. It would appear that the encoding is not `latin1` (aka ISO8859-1), `utf8`, or `ansinew`. However, that still leaves a lot of possibilities. Since only you have access to your files, only you can determine which input encoding is in force.

Comment: Undefined references are another problem. But ansinew should at least get rid of error messages from inputenc. Beside this: If you want help improve your question. Make a *complete* example, and show your log-file and the blg-file.

Comment: @mirette: `biblatex` is a package which can use `bibtex` as its bibliography engine as well as the more recent `biber`. To use all the possibilities of `biblatex`, it is better to compile the bibliography with `biber` – one of the main advantages is that it understands `utf8` (which you should use rather than `latin1` anyway. We can show you if you post a minimal compilable code (and probably a link to the template of your university, if possible).

Comment: @Bernard I have added the link (https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_6RXQUqktUOUG9peTZyOVBXZjg/view?usp=sharing) to my project all the references are replaced by [?] maybe you could help me when you see the files the whole template I will be gratefull for your support

Comment: @mirette: I've taken a look, and there are indeed problems on compiling. I don't have time at the moment, but I'll delve into it and try to solve these problems later.

Comment: @Bernard am very gratefull thank you a lot :)

Comment: @Mirette: Sorry for answer so late: I didn't have time to test he files in the link you posted. There was a problem in the class file `reportECD.cls` due to an ANSI encoding. I converted it to `utf8` and everything compiles fine, using `biber` for the bibliography. Is there any link where I could upload the converted files?

Answer (score 4):

Your bib-file has the followings errors:

- the entry `cornuejols2002nouvelle` uses an apostrophe that latex doesn't like. Rewrite the word as `d'apprentissage`.
- `chambrin2001alarms` has a faulty dash in pages
- `cornuejols2002nouvelle` has a faulty apostroph in the journal name.
- you are using \url in one entry but don't load the url or the hyperref package.

Your main file doesn't contain the command `\references`.

When I correct the bib, add the missing command and the page and compile with pdflatex + bibtex I get one missing entry:

```
  Warning--I didn't find a database entry for "HAL02"
```

Beside this it compiles without error.

Comment: thank you for your help for missing reference HAL023 It is just because Ihave created this project since I couldnot publish my thesis and soory for\references it has been deleated when I deleate my code soory ..  for `chambrin2001alarms    pages={184–-188},` soory where is the error here?   I still have the `package imputenc error` and only 14 of my references are showed the  other [?] here is the warning and error I got after I correct I the apostroph  in apprentissage and adding `\RequirePackage{url}` (https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_6RXQUqktUOdElkRkd1cjk3Yjg/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: I did not understand why all the warning related to 'undefined ref although alll of them exist :( and the inputenc error also :( am really stuck

Comment: Did you ran bibtex?

Comment: yes :( I do as follows f1, f12, than run the main file, then bibtex (the file which contain my references then I run my main file twice then pdf view but does not work for me :(

Comment: Did you add the command `\references` that I mention in my answer?

Answer (score 1):

With the following corrected MWE (see markings `<==============`, I added the missing call for the bibliography and style too)

```
% document de test pour le style rapportECD.cls (LaTeX2e)
% créé le 5 Décembre 2007 par Julien VELCIN pour le master ECD

% on utilise le stype défini dans rapportECD.cls
\documentclass{reportECD}

% le package ci-dessous (optionnel) permet de fusionner des lignes dans les tableau LaTeX
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{url} % <====================================================

% les champs suivants (title, author, date, tutors et place) doivent être obligatoirement renseignés
\title{Place here the title of your internship}
\author{Forename FAMILY\_NAME}
% indiquez ci-dessous la date de soutenance du stage
\date{06/29/2012}
\tutors{Supervisors and affiliations}
\place{Location of your internship}

% placez le logo du laboratoire d'accueil du stage ou de la société dans le répertoire /img au format .eps, puis indiquez le nom de l'image et la largeur désirée ci-dessous :
\logo{logoERIC}{25mm}

\begin{document}

% page de garde (obligatoire)
\maketitle

% résumé en anglais (obligatoire)
\begin{abstract}
Here is your abstract translated into english.
\end{abstract}

% résumé en français (obligatoire)
\begin{resume}
Le présent document est un exemple de fichier \LaTeX utilisant le style \texttt{reportECD.cls} qui décrit la structure d'un rapport de stage pour le Master ECD, rédigé en anglais.
Vous devez placer ici votre résumé en français.
Attention, l'en-tête de votre rapport, comprenant le titre, votre nom, la date, les logos \ldots et les résumés en français et en anglais, ne doit pas dépasser 1 page au total (il s'agit de la couverture).
\end{resume}

% table des matières (obligatoire)
\tabledesmatieres

\section{Hosting institution}

Cette section décrit la structure d'accueil du stage (laboratoire, entreprise, autre).
Elle ne doit pas faire plus d'une ou deux pages.

\section{Acknowledgement}

Cette section est optionnelle et vous permet, si vous le souhaitez, de remercier les personnes de votre choix qui vous ont aidé durant votre stage.

\newpage

\section{Introduction}

Cette section contient la description du problème à traiter (en précisant bien les difficultés soulevées), suivi par la solution qui est proposée dans les grandes lignes.
Elle se termine par l'annonce du plan qui structure le rapport.

Les références à des ouvrages ou des articles de recherche sont vivement encouragées et doivent suivre le format bibtex (voir le fichier d'exemple \texttt{biblio.bib}).
Tous les détails sur ce format sont donnés sur le site internet suivant : \texttt{http://www.bibtex.org/}.
Cela donne des références dans votre rapport sous la forme ci-après : \cite{HAL02}.

\section{Exemple de section}

Vous pouvez commencer à détailler bla bla.
here is my references \cite{knuth1998art, guan2002incremental, zhou2002hybrid, chao2008incremental, liu2008incremental, wang2006diagnosis, ccalicsir2011new, yilmaz2013expert, leung2007naive, soman2005classification, wang2013statistical, chambrin2001alarms, vapnik1963pattern, de2013mrmre, kurgan2001knowledge, cios2002hybrid, ivanciuc2007applications, chujai2017cluster, sobran2013classification, chawla2002smote, wu2008top, burges1998tutorial, fletcher2009support, hariharan:2013, hsu2003practical, kumari2013classification}
fffffff \cite{agrawal2008incremental,wang2012evolving, guan2006incremental, liu2015neural, guan2004incremental, guan2001incremental, chao2010knowledge, zhu2004ordered} ggggg \cite{guan2005incremental, friedman2001elements, utgoff1989incremental, utgo1994improved, utgo1996kolmogorov, blake1998uci, grosan2006swarm, katakis2006dynamic, wang2011ordered, he2016incremental, peng2005feature, davisongary, nayak2015comprehensive, kumar2012classification, shah2004sequential, booker1989classifier, grossman2004learning, boser1992training, cornuejols2002nouvelle, priyadarshini2015map, durgesh2010data, cornuejols2011apprentissage, byun2002applications, guo2000face, guo2001support, drucker1999support, sewak2007svm, kohli2010svm, suykens1999least, polat2007breast}

\bibliographystyle{plain} % <===========================================
\bibliography{biblio} % <===============================================

\end{document}
```

and the both corrected bib entrys

```
@article{cornuejols2002nouvelle,
  title={Une nouvelle m{\'e}thode d`apprentissage: Les SVM. S{\'e}parateurs {\`a} vaste marge},
  author={Cornu{\'e}jols, Antoine},
  journal={Bulletin de l`AFIA},
  volume={51},
  pages={14--23},
  year={2002}
}
```

and

```
@article{chambrin2001alarms,
  title={Alarms in the intensive care unit: how can the number of false alarms be reduced?},
  author={Chambrin, Marie-Christine},
  journal={Critical Care},
  volume={5},
  number={4},
 pages={184--188},
  year={2001},
  publisher={BioMed Central}
}
```

I can compile your code without errors following the usual chain:

```
pdflatex mwe.tex
bibtex mwe
pdflatex mwe.tex
pdflatex mwe.tex
```

The result are only two warnings, because `\cite{HAL02}` tries to cite an bib entry not contained in your bib file ...

Comment: thank you for your time and consideration I have just seen you answer I am goinna trying it I hope it solves the problm since am till now stuck very happy to see a feedback thank you :) dont be so far ;) am trying it thank you :)

Comment: I am desperate the references appear but stil errors (https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_6RXQUqktUOYmJvd2thMmF3bm8/view?usp=sharing) and somthing strange does happen I have some references I have delete them because I added them just to see why this problm particularly ( `guan2006incremental `  `utgo1996kolmogorov kumar2012classification  ccalicsir2011new soman2005classification hsu2003practical` please any explanation ! I have delate them from biblio.bib and Idid not logically call anyof them but they still exist did not understand very strange,does references stored somewhere from the start?

Comment: @mirette These are the old errors. You seem not have cleaned the bib correctly or your reverted to an older version. Beside this: This site is not the suitable place to correct your problem. You need someone who can sit beside you and see what you do and tell you when you do something wrong.