# references are displayed strangly including some characters

Tags: bibliographies

here is one of my references i use `\bibliographystyle{plain}`
 `@article{chambrin2001alarms,
  title={Alarms in the intensive care unit: how can the number of false alarms be reduced?},
  author={Chambrin, Marie-Christine},
  journal={Critical Care},
  volume={5},
  number={4},
 pages={184–-188},
  year={2001},
  publisher={BioMed Central}
}` it gives me an error and displayed as you see [image: figure] 184a^ - 188 even that there is no a^

```
\documentclass{article}
\RequirePackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\RequirePackage{fancyhdr}
  blabla \cite{chambrin2001alarms}
  \end{document}
```

Comment: Try to delete `--` and retype it. As you can see the first one is no `-` but longer.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/384987/36296 already told you about the faulty dash!

Comment: I have deleate it then retype it but always same problm I did not find how to fix it

Comment: Delete all auxiliary files and compile again. If this does not help, make a [minimal working example with bibliography (MWEB)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407). (code fragments which would not produce a bibliography even if completed to a compilable document, don't count)

Comment: Look closely at the field `pages={184–-188}`, and observe that the second "dash" character isn't the same as the first. One of these two characters is the character that's giving you grief. (My guess is that the first is the culprit.) Delete *both* characters and type in `--` (using ordinary dashes) instead, delete the `aux` and `bbl` files, and rerun LaTeX, BibTeX, and LaTeX twice more to get a new, clean bibliography.

Comment: thank you guys for your support and excuse me ( but really I did know am gonna try  with your tips thank you :) )

Comment: It works finnalyyy thank you thank you the problm is that I didnot dealeate aux and bbl files ones done it works thank you :) am very gratefull :)